# Mongoose custom _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make only one user with custom _id and other's with default value.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId() },
  password: String,
  fName: String,
  lName: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  blogs: [blogSchema],
  followers: Array,
  followings: Array,
  darkMode: Boolean,
});
```

Custom id works, user has _id as string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngGzE.png)

But the others value type is also a string not ObjectId.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zuD5.png)

**Is it way to convert this default _id to ObjectId?**

**Or will there be any problem if I left it as a string?**

Comment: In general, you can store any value for a field, including for the `_id` field. But, Mongoose enforces schema validation. [Mongoose Validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) says, you can _"You can disable automatic validation before save by setting the validateBeforeSave option"_. You need to verify, if this works for the `_id`  field.

Comment: So if i left _id field as a string nothing will change, right?